# android BluetoothGattServer disconnects after some time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Maybe someone have some experience with new Android Lollipop Bluetooth API where device can play a peripheral role.After I opened a server and started advertising service with characteristics some central device connects to my device,read my data,but than for some reason Gatt server disconnects.Any ideas why this might happen?It is repeated with both iOS and Android device as centrals

Comment: Going through the same thing right now. I setup a peripheral and a central and the connection will be dropped some seconds after writing a characteristic. Did you find a solution for this?